# My guessing game repeatedly prints in console if you guess incorrectly

Tags: python

I am new to python and built this for practice. How come if you guess incorrectly the print function runs repeatedly. Additionally, if you make a correct guess the corresponding print function doesn't run.

```
import random

print("Welcome to the Guessing Game")

rand = random.randint(1, 9)
count = 0
running = True

guess = int(input("Pick a number from 1 - 9"))

while guess != rand:
    count += 1
    if guess > rand:
        print("Too High")
        running = False
    elif guess == rand:
        print("Winner Winner Chicken Dinner")
        print("You won in", count, "tries!")
        running = False
    elif guess < rand:
        print("Too Low")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number is incorrect we need to ask the player to guess again. You can use `break` to avoid having an infinite loop, here after 5 guesses.
The conversion of the input to integer will throw an error if the entry is not a valid number. It would be good to implement error handling.

```
import random

print("Welcome to the Guessing Game")

rand = random.randint(1, 9)
count = 0
running = True

guess = int(input("Pick a number from 1 - 9"))

while guess != rand:
    count += 1
    if guess > rand:
        print("Too High")
        running = False
    elif guess == rand:
        print("Winner Winner Chicken Dinner")
        print("You won in", count, "tries!")
        running = False
        break
    elif guess < rand:
        print("Too Low")
    if i >= 5:
        break
    guess = int(input("Try again\nPick a number from 1 - 9"))
```

Answer (score 0):

in the first while loop, when player guesses the correct number we need to break.

Also for counting the number of rounds that player played we need a new while loop based on count.

When we use count in our code we should ask player every time that he enters the wrong answer to guess again so i used input in the while

```
import random

print("Welcome to the Guessing Game:")

rand = random.randint(1, 9)
count = 0


while count!=5:
    guess = int(input("Pick a number from 1 - 9:"))
    count += 1
    if guess > rand:
        print("Too High")
    
    
    elif guess == rand:
        print("Winner Winner Chicken Dinner")
        print("You won in", count, "tries!")
        break
    elif guess < rand:
        print("Too Low")

print('you lost')
```